# Javascript jQuery Map reloadable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, draggable, reload

Similar questions have been asked before, but there is something I need all the others map di not require:

How can I design a draggable map, but not with a limited area, but with huge one, parts of which need to be reloaded during dragging?

How big should I make the draggable div? All the way up to the whole potential map? Or only slightly bigger than the visible area and then reload the parts scrolled into view with a dynamic offset?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the reloaded parts (that are scrolled into view) need to be reloaded from the server. It's a 1000x1000 map, the visible area is only about 9x9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys, seeing that nobody wants to answer it: I found the solution.

Knowing the size of the map, it doesn't cause any kind of performance issues to use a background div with the corresponding dimensions, like 15,000x15000px or even more. Just create a parent container, set it to `overflow: hidden;` and put that tremendous map into it. It's best to set its position to absolute and move it by adapting the margin. The margin-top and margin-left properties can be easily modified via JavaScript.

Also, that huge div can have child elements. Create a child element that is positioned `relative`-ly, and fill that relative element with whatever you would like to show on the map, calculating the distances of the items relative to the world's top-left corner. When the map is moved, you can check if the margin has exceeded a certain point, and, if it has, reload those elements via AJAX.

Your code would look more or less like that:

```
<div id="viewport" style="overflow: hidden;">

    <div id="map" style="position: absolute; width: 15000px; height: 15000px;">

        <div id="container" style="position: relative;">

            <div id="element_1" style="position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 100px; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            <div id="element_2" style="position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 80px; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            <div id="element_3" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 10px; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            <div id="element_4" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            <div id="element_5" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

It would be the the element `container` which you would then re-feed via AJAX with whatever has to be shown corresponding to the margin of `map`.